# after sending some put method my json file become empty

Tags: javascript, node.js, json, express

when I am working on restapi
after sending some put method my json file become empty

**my courses.json file**

this file contain locally

[courses.json](https://github.com/Bijusrt/Saral-Api-Using-Node.js/blob/master/availableCourses.json)

**app.js file**

In this app.js file I am seding put request
to update my courses.json file

```
'use strict'

const express = require('express')

const Courses = require('./modals/courses.js')

const app = express();
app.use(express.json())


app.put('/course/:courseid',async(req,res) => {
    const updateCourse = await new Courses(req.params.courseid,req.body.name,req.body.description)
    await updateCourse.putCourse()
    await Courses.fetchCourses(courses => {
        res.send(courses)
    })
})

app.listen(3000,()=>{
    console.log('hey dude I am listing...')
})
```

**courses.js file**

here In this courses.js file
by putCourse()  method
I am reading and writing in
json file

```
'use sririct'

const path = require('path')
const fs = require('fs')


const readFileCourses = (cb) => {
    fs.readFile(path.join(__dirname,'..','data','courses.json'),(err,data) => {
        if (!err) {
            cb(JSON.parse(data))
        }else{
            console.log(err)
        }
    })
}

class Courses {
    constructor (id,name,description) {
        this.id = id,
        this.name = name,
        this.description = description
    }
    static fetchCourses(cb) { 
        readFileCourses(cb)
    }
    putCourse() {
        readFileCourses(async courses => {
            const updateCourseIndex = await courses.findIndex(p => p.id == this.id)  
            // const updateCourses = await [...courses]
            if (this.hasOwnProperty('name')){
                courses[updateCourseIndex].name = await this.name
            }
            if (this.hasOwnProperty('description')){
                courses[updateCourseIndex].description = await this.description
            }
            fs.writeFile(path.join(__dirname,'..','data','courses.json'),JSON.stringify(courses,null,4),err => {
                console.log(err)
            })
        })
    }
}

module.exports = Courses
```

Comment: Might want to check the docs for `writeFile`, in particular, the mode flag.

Comment: You can pass a flag in writeFile to append data to an existing file.

fs.writeFile(__dirname,'..','data','courses.json'),JSON.stringify(courses,null,4),  {'flag':'a'},  function(err) {
    if (err) {
        return console.error(err);
    }
});